# after using grunt uglify task, my site is lack of all js, css files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I used grunt uglify to generate all minified js,css for my site in a dist/ folder...

My app folder at the moment looks like this:

```
app
dist
    scripts
       controllers
       services
       directives
bower_components
node_modules
```

and my site structure used to look like this:

```
app 
  scripts
     controllers
     services
     directives
bower_components
node_modules
```

and my index.html looks like this:

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/AuthController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/UserController.js"></script>
```

and router.js looked like this:

```
resolve: {
                loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'venture',
                        files: [
                            'scripts/controllers/CaptableController.js',
                            'scripts/controllers/TeamController.js',
                            'scripts/services/TeamService.js',
                        ]
                    })
                }
            }
```

The thing is my site now is not working if I change the path to every reference to dist/scripts/.... of all js,css scripts.

Comment: paths should be `min.js` and `min.css`

Comment: @Bxx could you be more specific what do you mean by min.js and min.css and it does not seem that grunt has changed file names to min.js to any of them

Comment: where is your index.html located?

Comment: @JLewkovich it is under app/index.html

Comment: Then you may have to do `../dist/scripts/`

Comment: I did this, but still not working, says 404 not found

Comment: @HisniFazlija are you using `.min` paths _and_ `../dist/scripts`?

Comment: no, I could not make it works